# How do I deploy a contract complied with solc?

Tags: go-ethereum, solidity, ethereum-wallet-dapp, solc

I am trying to deploy a contract that I have compiled with `solc` using `solc --bin mycontract.sol`.

I used to be able to paste the result into Ethereum-Wallet and deploy the contract this way. However, this does not work for this contract (I expect the binary code is to large).

I have tried for a few hours now but I simply can not find a guide showing how to deploy a contract in any other way. But I am guessing I should be able to do it somehow using the `geth` commandline tool.

I could potentially just paste the solidity code into Ethereum-Wallet and let it compile the code. However, the contract uses imports which I am not sure how to get into Ethereum-Wallet.

Answer (score 3):

You can do it, by using online compiler and geth commandline.

Step 1: First copy your contract into https://ethereum.github.io/browser-solidity/ , on the right handside of your page you would see Bytecode,Interface,Web3 deploy and uDApp text fields. What you should be interested here is the `web3 deploy` text field.

Step 2: copy the text into your geth commandline , just paste and you would see , something like `Contract mined! address: 0x.... transactionHash: 0x.....`

Now you can use the contract address.

Comment: I tried doing that, but I never see the "Contract mined!..." message. I am doing this on the testnet though. I think the testnet might be having some problems. At least blocks are being generated very infrequently.

Comment: Are you connected to the network ( main or testnet )? or are you running in private network if so , are you mining ? @GuutBoy

Comment: I am running on the testnet (morden).

Comment: Also, this does not really answer the question. I specifically do not want to use the browser compiler, just solc.

Comment: what are the geth arguments are you passing ? See if you have --verbosity 6 , this would help you test if you have enough ether, to be able to publish, and set your account by eth.defaultAccount and eth.coinbase etc.

Comment: Browser compiler is just giving few additional things wrappers  around  the bytecode which you could deploy easily on geth console. The binary data/byte code  generated in both the cases would be same.